# TS2345: Argument of type 'Role[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object[]'

Tags: arrays, angular, object

I am using Angular 8.

I am facing this `'Role[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'object[]'`

Did I implement the `checkRoleExist` and the `allowedToAccess` wrongly?

Role Enum class:

```
export enum Role {
  A = 'role-a',
  B = 'role-b',
  C = 'role-c',
  D = 'role-d',
  E = 'role-e',
}
```

I have a util class:

```
export function allowedToAccess(allowedRoles: object[], currentRoles: object[]) {
  let i: number;

  if (currentRoles === undefined || currentRoles === null || allowedRoles === undefined || allowedRoles === null) {
    return false;
  }
  console.log('allowedRoles:' + allowedRoles);
  console.log('currentRoles:' + currentRoles);

  allowedRoles.forEach(givenAllowedRoles => checkRoleExist(givenAllowedRoles, currentRoles))

  for(i = 0; i < allowedRoles.length; i++) {
    if (checkRoleExist(allowedRoles[i], currentRoles)) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function checkRoleExist(allowedRoles: object, currentRoles: object[]) : boolean {

  /**
   * allowedRoles : [[Role.A, Role.B], Role.C, [Role.D], Role.E]
   * currentRoles : [Role.A, Role.B]
   */

  /**
   * allowedRoles : [[Role.A, Role.B], Role.C, [Role.D], Role.E]
   * currentRoles : [Role.A]
   */

  /**
   * allowedRoles : [[Role.A, Role.B], Role.C, [Role.D], Role.E]
   * currentRoles : [Role.E]
   */

  /**
   * allowedRoles : [[Role.A, Role.B], Role.C, [Role.D], Role.E]
   * currentRoles : [Role.A, Role.B, Role.F]
   */

  // check if allowedRoles is an array
  if (Array.isArray(allowedRoles)) {
    allowedRoles.forEach(allowedRole => {
      if (!currentRoles.includes(allowedRole)) {
        return false;
      }
    })

    return true;
  }

  // allowedRoles is an object
  return currentRoles.includes(allowedRoles);
}
```

In my header class:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  constructor(
    ...
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
this.credentialsService.currentUserSubject.subscribe((u: User) => {
      const currentUserRoles: Role[] = u.role.slice();

      this.navigationlinks = [
        {
          id: 'library',
          label: 'library',
          index: 0,
          icon: '../assets/header/library.svg',
          disabledIcon: '../assets/header/library_disabled.svg',
          render: allowedToAccess([Role.A, Role.B], currentUserRoles),
          isActive: false,
          subLinks: [
...
```

Error log:

```
src/app/shell/header/header.component.ts:43:59 - error TS2322: Type 'Role.A' is not assignable to type 'object'.

43           render: allowedToAccess([Role.A, Role.B], currentUserRoles),
```

Comment: Why are you using object anyway? Use Role.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have cases like `[[Role.A, Role.B], Role.C, [Role.D], Role.E]`

Comment: You can represent that as `(Role | Role[])[]`, or if it can have arbitrary depth even use a recursive type like https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwEoQDbDgbwCg44BBOAXjgHIodgBaAQ2oBpi4AhSmu3BgEZsOAYR616DAMbCSAEXF9GAE1lwAoosnBhAX0KEYATzB4suABI5lwKDwAU5vAB9M9K9htQAlAG0AugDcBlIQiADO8DAAFgCWiADmAFxulta2PL6+TgB0pKypwDmc-gW5IgXZ9DlypYU56kGEQA.

Comment: I got it. thanks @jonrsharpe